# Filtering a data frame by month using filter(month()) and running into error Error in `filter()`

Tags: r, dataframe, character, filtering

I'm attempting to create a new data frame called mirage.long from another data frame called mirage.merged that only includes data from the month of may. But when attempting to do so I receive the error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
ℹ In argument: `month(jotDateTime) == 5`.
Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

This is my code:

```
search.month.num <- 5
mirage.long <- mirage.merged %>% 
  filter(grepl('play', marker)) %>% 
  filter(month(jotDateTime)==search.month.num) %>% 
  select(participantID, marker, UTC)
```

what can I do to fix this?

I have tried to `filter(month("jotDateTime")==search.month.num)` 
and  using `as.numeric()` to convert character into a numerical value but its says:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your data. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Have you tried converting the number into a date first, then into month? That would be less ambiguous: `filter(month(jotDateTime) == as_date(ymd(paste("2023", search.month.num, "01"))) %>% month())`